# Resize individual image in widget - magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have created customize theme which extends to magento blank. I am using widget to show latest products in home page.

Now, My page look like this

[image: easy for your reference]

I want to resize the every image (catalog product list) in widget. I will expect my page look like this

[image: expected result]

**Note :** I could refer this [link](http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-change-the-image-size-in-listing-page/) to change all image size but no luck. copy view.xml from blank theme, paste into app/design/..../mytheme/etc/view.xml. I change below content in view.xml

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>400</width>
    <height>400</height>
</image>
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
    <width>400</width>
    <height>400</height>
</image>
```

but nothing get reflected

here I put two questions

1. How to resize individual image in product list
2. Why mytheme view.xml get not reflected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you can define any new image type in the view.xml. To use it you have to pass the image id to the image helper used like here for example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php#L60

2) if I got the right widget here, you have to override a differrent image id:

grid: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml#L21

list: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml#L21

So you would have to override these images in your view.xml:

grid: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/etc/view.xml#L55

list: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/etc/view.xml#L59

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Give me sometime I am working with your answer. after while I come back to you.

Comment: Wow great geneious, its working. you have given right answer to second question. I up vote you. I have one doubt, how you find image id for appropriate task

Comment: You have to locate the template or Block file to see which image definition is used. Currently, many core features rely on having the related images defined in your view.xml. I hope this will be more flexible in the future. Some images are hardcoded in the Core Modules and if they are not defined in the view.xml you will get an error

Comment: I can't get clear, image definition? . In temlate file only mention the class

Comment: i updated the answer. The Product Gallery for example creates the images in the block. The Image Helper can create resized images for you by passing the image id defined in your view.xml like here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php#L60

Comment: give me sometime I am working with your answer. I will be back to you

Comment: I have declared the new type with id "new_products_content_widget_list" it will affect whole image in new product list,  but I need to set height & width to individual image

Comment: if you want to add an individual image type for your widget, you would have to extend the widget itself https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/widget.xml#L42 and set a new template, which uses your own image type, but this would exceed the scope of this question I think

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I can achieve the individual image height and width by using CSS nth-child selector. As well as I accepted your answer is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37078/discussion-between-bilal-usean-and-david-verholen).